# Use Variable in multiple subs VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

So I'm using excel 2010, and right now, I'm trying to use calculate the value of a variable in one sub, and want it to be used in multiple subs, except I can't figure out how to do this. Here is an example of what I'm using in its most basic form

```
Public Sub Calc()
Dim i As Integer
i = 10 - 5    
End Sub


'Other sub that will use the value for i calculated in the Calc sub

Sub Macro()
y = i +5
End Sub
```

How am I suppose to be able to use/pass this value for "i" in/into the sub macro?

Answer (score 3):

Move the `Dim` **above** the subs:

```
Public i As Integer

Public Sub Calc()
    i = 10 - 5
End Sub

Sub Macro()
    y = i + 5
    MsgBox y
End Sub

Sub MAIN()
    Call Calc
    Call Macro
End Sub
```

Try running `MAIN()`

Answer (score 2):

Insert new module and define `i` as:

```
Public i As Integer
```

Then you'll be able to use it whenever you want.

For further information, please see: [Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141693)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use Function instead of Sub.

```
Sub Main()
  Msgbox Macro(calc)
end Sub

Function Calc() as Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 10 - 5    
  Calc = i
End Function

Function Macro(i as Integer) as Integer
  Macro = i + 5
End Function
```